# Is there a way to call sleep() without await keyword?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I want to call `sleep()` function without the `await` keyword before it. To achieve this, I tried with another *wrapper-async* function `sleepAsync(x, callback)` with callback but it didn't work.

Here is my code -

```
function color() {
  let string1 = "yellow yeelow";
  console.log(string1);
  let string2 = "blu glu";
  console.log(string2);
  let string3 = "green freen";
  console.log(string3);
}

async function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms * 1000));
}
```

Now the function call where it works correctly -

```
async function fcall(loop = 2) {
  for (let x = loop; x > 0; x--) {
    color();
    await sleep(2);
  }
}

fcall(4);
```

In the above way of calling, each iteration waits for 2 sec before continuing.

Below code is where `sleep()` doesn't wait for 2 sec -

```
async function sleepAsync(x, callback) {
    callback();
    await sleep(x);
  }

  function gcall(loop = 2) {
    for (let x = loop; x > 0; x--) {
      sleepAsync(2, color);
    }
  }

  gcall(4);
```

What can be done here? and where am I making mistake?

Comment: Sleep is not a part of JS program design, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: If you want to do sleep each tick of a loop _without_ the async keyword, I think you might have to refactor it to a recursive function. But the question is why.

Comment: I want to pause execution for certain seconds and then resume back. So, how can I make it happen without writing `await` before every `sleep()` call.

Comment: Regarding the question of why I would want to do that, the answer is - curiosity. I am kind of new to JS and was wondering, is there a way, hence the question.

Comment: async / await can be transpiled to make it work on browsers that don't support this syntax, so yes there is a way. If you want to make it work on older browsers, then the answer is "use a transpiler", if you really wish to learn how it could be rewritten by hand, then try to do it, and come back here if you face an issue while trying to do it.

Comment: Your code and logic may not be a bit faulty. First of all, you don't need to wrap a promise in async function, so wrapping the loop in async await in second block does not serve any purpose. If you need a delayed execution, directly use setTimeout unless you need to chain two delayed or async functions, in that case promise chain or two async function is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An async function will not work at the exact time if the rest of the code after is not waiting for it.

When codes start running each statement will be added to a queue and the runner will start reading using that queue. An async funtion will be added to the end of the queue.

Assume this code:

```
let a = true;
doSomething();
doSomethingAsync();
doSomething2();
```

The queue to be executed can be like this:

```
let a
doSomething
doSomething2
doSomethingAsync
```

But of you use `await` the async code will be added to that position where you invoked it. So adding `await doSomethingAsync();` will make the queue like this:

```
let a
doSomthing
doSomethingAsync
doSomething2
```

**TL; DR**

> You use `await` when you want the code to be executed now, not put it at the queue.

Comment: Alright, understood. Thanks. So I guess I will have to use await. no other way..

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use an external package, and async won't work for reasons, the `sleep` package now recommends using the built-in Atomics.wait (which is included in node after node 9.3), like so:

```js
function msleep(n) {
  Atomics.wait(new Int32Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(4)), 0, 0, n);
}
function sleep(n) {
  msleep(n*1000);
}
```

I've used this successfully in production.

Source: [sleep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sleep` package from npm, see it at https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep.

Comment: Thanks, but I was actually looking for solution that doesn't depend on that package. Like some code change or something.

Comment: You can try use `child_process.execSync` with `timeout` options, for example:

```typescript
function sleep(timeout) {
  try {
    child_process.execSync(`sleep ${Math.ceil(timeout / 1e3)}`, { timeout })
  } catch {
    return
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS has a *run to completion guarantee*, so if you call `color()` it is guaranteed to run completely
 There is no way to halt the execution of it in any way. There are however *async functions* and *generator functions* that can be run piecewise (meaning: till an `await` or `yield` is reached), so if you don't want to use `await`, you have to `yield`:

```
 function* color() {
   let string1 = "yellow yeelow";
   console.log(string1);
   yield;

   let string2 = "blu glu";
   console.log(string2);
    yield;

    let string3 = "green freen";
    console.log(string3);
  }

  async function sleep(ms) {
     return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,  ms * 1000));
  }


  async function fcall() {
     const it = color();
     let done = false;
     while(!done) {
       ({ done } = it.next());
       await sleep(2);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I did not think of using yield in that way. Thanks for that.